# How to reveal available keyboard shortcuts in dialogs in RubyMine?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, rubymine

I use RubyMine on Macs. Until recently (until I upgraded to RubyMine 7, I think), in RubyMine dialogs, such as Find in Path and Commit Changes, when I held down the option key, I'd see underlines under letters in field labels so I'd know what option-whatever key combination would select or move focus to the corresponding fields. That doesn't work for me these days. Is there a setting (whether in RubyMine or Mac OS) I can change to get it back?

Or, less preferably is there some other way to expose keyboard shortcuts in dialogs on the fly? (I know about the keymap reference and the keymap preferences; those aren't relevant to dialogs and definitely aren't on the fly.)

RubyMine 7.0.1 and OS X 10.9.5, in case it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is covered by [an IDEA bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111466). It was in some versions of Java 7 and 8. It must have appeared on my machine when I accepted an upgrade from Java 6 to 7. There are two solutions:

- Under an affected version of Java, use control-option instead of just option to reveal the shortcuts.
- Upgrade to a current version of Java 7 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

I use Find Action (command, shift, A) whenever a keyboard shortcut doesn't work or if I forget it. write the name of the action you want. I love this feature.

Comment: Good feature, but doesn't help with navigating to fields on dialogs.